# Why isn't our blog appearing on the blogoverflow.com main page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog

At the moment, I see 15 blogs listed on [blogoverflow.com](http://blogoverflow.com/). Some blogs already contain many posts, some blogs less than ours. And I think our [TeX blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/) is of good quality.

Isn't it ready to be shown on blogoverflow.com?

What do you think can be done to bring it forward?

Comment: According to http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/ the requirement to graduate the blog are "We want to see continued contributions and interest in the blog as time proceeds. We want to see that you’re promoting the blog, making use of the community promotion ads if they are enabled on your site. We want to see that people from the community are interested in and reading the blog."

Comment: The TeX blog looks [graduated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509): the link at the page bottom points to http://tex.blogoverflow.com/ and http://blog.tex.stackexchange.com/ leads to it. I guess visibility on `blogoverflow.com` doesn't depend on graduation, as some sites listed there still have a sketchy layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange Community Blogs are listed on the Blog Overflow homepage the moment their first post goes up.

There were several encoding errors in [TUG 2011, Day Two](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/tug-2011-day-two) that were screwing up the RSS feed.  This prevented the feed from being properly parsed and displayed on the homepage.

I've fixed these errors and the TeX blog is properly listed on the Blog Overflow homepage again.

Comment: That's a good explanation why it wasn't visible when I checked it. Thanks for fixing!